# How to get a specific value for list [python]__For Beginner

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have this kind of list.

```
info = [['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']]
```

If I try

```
print(info[0])
```

I obviously get ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'] this list.

Bur I only want to get : 'x1', 'x3' and 'y1', 'y3' (specific values)

Is there any solution? Thanks

Comment: print(info[0][0], info[0][2]) The second subscript refers to indexes in the sublist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About lists:

So you have a list:

```
info = [['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']]

#       [                      ]  [                      ]
#             info[0]                   info[1]
```

As you said `0` is the first element of the list.

However, if we have a list inside a list, we can select the items we want by specifically targeting their index:

```
info = [['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']]
#       ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
#        [0]    [1]   [2]   [3]    [0]   [1]   [2]    [3]
#       [                      ]  [                      ]
#             info[0]                   info[1]
```

So, to get specific 'x1', 'x3' and 'y1', 'y3'

```
print(info[0][0], info[0][2], info[1][0], info[1][2])
```

Another method would be list slicing:

```
#       ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
#       [            :         ]  [          :           ]

#Slicing [start:stop:step]
# info[0][:] ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
```

And if you run: `print(info[0][::2])`

You get: `['x1', 'x3']`

Foy y, you run `info[1][::2]`.

Another way would be to loop through the list

```
for sublist in info:
 print(sublist[1], sublist[3])
 # or
 print(sublist[::2])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a nested list. So access the elements inside the inner list, you need to something like this:

```
In [103]: info = [['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']]

In [104]: info[0][1]
Out[104]: 'x2'

In [105]: info[1][1]
Out[105]: 'y2'
```

If you are planning to use for loop to access the element, then you need to iterate twice.

Answer (score 0):

info is 2D list, it's mean it is a list of lists. when you get the first element of info by `info[0]` it returns the `['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']` if you want to get first element of x, y you can do it like this:

```
print(info[0][0], info[1][0])
```

you can also use `zip` to get x, y together in tuple:

```
zip_info = zip(info[0], info[1])
print(zip_info[0])
```

Output:

```
(x1, y1)
```